# Extract list of objects from WSDL XML with XPath

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xpath, wsdl

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataSet xmlns="http://MRCS/">
  <xs:schema id="Estacoes" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="Estacoes" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Table">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="NomeEstacao" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="CodEstacao" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Bacia" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="SubBacia" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Operadora" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Responsavel" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Municipio-UF" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Latitude" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Longitude" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Altitude" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="CodRio" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="NomeRio" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Origem" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="StatusEstacao" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <Estacoes xmlns="">
      <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <NomeEstacao>GUARAPUAVA - COLÉGIO AGRICOLA</NomeEstacao>
        <CodEstacao>02551010</CodEstacao>
        <Bacia>6</Bacia>
        <SubBacia>65</SubBacia>
        <Operadora>00067 - IAPAR - IAPAR</Operadora>
        <Responsavel>00067 - IAPAR - IAPAR</Responsavel>
        <Municipio-UF>GUARAPUAVA-PR</Municipio-UF>
        <Latitude>-25.36470</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-51.49690</Longitude>
        <Altitude>1045.00</Altitude>
        <CodRio>0</CodRio>
        <NomeRio/>
        <Origem>ANA/SIVAM</Origem>
        <StatusEstacao>Ativo</StatusEstacao>
      </Table>
    </Estacoes>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

From which i want to extract the `<Table>` element. If i use xpath(/*) i can get the entire document, but i can't figure out a way to extract certain elements from it. Is it even possible to use XPath with WSDL XMLs?

EDIT: i am using PostgreSQL xpath function to query from a XML column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of handling the quite complex issue with the various namespaces on that document you can select this `Table` element with the XPath expression

```
xpath(/*/*/*/Table)
```

It selects all `Table` elements on every fourth level.

Comment: It works! So every * is entering a node ? Do you know of any tutorial explaining XPath usage in situations like this?

Comment: `*` does select _any element_, so it's essentially _/any/any/any/Table_.

Comment: IMHO one good _beginners tutorial_ for XPath is [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp). Some may object, but I think it's a good intro.

Comment: This won’t work in Java, as that XPath expression assumes a `Table` element with no namespace.

Comment: If this shouldn't work due to namespace issues, use `/*/*/*/*[local-name()='Table']`.

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL xpath function